# Table command in Latex

Tags: tables

I have this table[image]

I want writ it in latex, Unfortunately I do not know how to do, please help me

Thanks

Comment: this is good site [wiki/LaTeX/Tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) for learning how to make tables in Latex

Comment: Your screenshot shows *two* tables -- which one are you interested in? The header of the second table looks to be seriously messed up: Do you want to reproduce all mistakes?

Comment: @Dear Mic, I I'm need to both

Comment: Please be more specific about what you need to do.  Is the data in an external file?  Then consider using the [`pgfplotstable` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable).  If the data is in the main file, have a look at the [`booktabs` package and its documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).  In either case, there are several existing questions here that will help.  Look at those and post the LaTeX code you have tried if you can't get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to get you started. Note that because the first table mostly consists of math material, I suggest using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. I also recommend aligning the numbers in the second table on their decimal markers; one way to do so is to load the `siunitx` package and use its `S` column type. The formatting of the captions is handled most easily by loading the `caption` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,siunitx,caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false,
              skip=0pt}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} %choose margins appropriately
\newenvironment{smalltab}%
    {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\bfseries}c@{}}}%
    {\end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mysim{{\sim}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Value and distribution of input parameters}
$
\begin{array}{@{} *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\smash[b]{\begin{smalltab} Value \& \\ Distribution \\ \end{smalltab}}
& \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{\textbf{Parameter}}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& n & w_{ij}^c & C_{ij}^c & f_k^q & \mathrm{cap}_{k}^q & t_{kl}^m \\
\midrule
& 30\#8 & p\mysim(20) & U\mysim(1,10) & U\mysim(1000,2000) & U\mysim(100,1000) & U\mysim(10,20)\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
$
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Comparison metrics for small-sized problems}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\bfseries}c *{6}{S[table-format=1.3]} @{}}
\toprule
Problem No. & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Quality Metric (QM)}
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{\bfseries Spacing Metric (SM)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
& {PAES} & {NSGA-II} & {MOPSA} & {PAES} & {NSGA-II} & {MOPSA} \\
\midrule
10\#3 & 0 & 0.115 & 0.695 & 0.545 & 0.657 & 0.741 \\
\vdots\\
30\#8 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0.327 & 0.296 & 0.745 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```